# Post-hocs from glmmTMB with odd results

Tags: emmeans, glmmtmb

I am running a zero-inflated gaussian glmm in glmmTMB to compare a continuous variable (CPUE) with mean+- SD 1.74+-8.45 (min.-max.: 0-85.52) among four factor levels (factor type). All values of CPUE for one of my factor levels are 0, whereas in the other cases there are some non-zero positive values. I ran my model using this:

`glmmTMB(cpue~type+(1|site),data=combined_data,ziformula= ~1,family=gaussian)`,

and performed post-hocs (after checking the significance of the type factor) with emmeans as

`pairs(emmeans(model_cpue,~type),adjust="fdr")`*.*

Which gives me the following results:

`contrast  estimate    SE  df t.ratio p.value`

`ACO - ACT  -40.813 19.26 281  -2.119  0.0700`

`ACO - BAT  -31.826 19.13 281  -1.664  0.1459`

`ACO - TRA   -0.133 18.99 281  -0.007  0.9944`

`ACT - BAT    8.986  5.99 281   1.499  0.1620`

`ACT - TRA   40.680  5.52 281   7.365  <.0001`

`BAT - TRA   31.694  5.04 281   6.286  <.0001`

`P value adjustment: fdr method for 6 tests`

The residuals of the model are ok, and everything seems to work fine. However, the level ACO is precisely the one with all 0 values, and yet it does not present significant differences with the remaining levels (which have some non-zero values), whereas these do among each other. Does anyone know why would this happen? Could it be because zero-inflation is smoothing the differences? I tried modelling the ZI as ziformula=~type, with no difference.

I appreciate any comment on this. Thank you in advance

Comment: Remember that by default, emmeans support for a glmmTMB model works with the component part of the model. You are not making an inference for the overall means, which are a combination of the zero part and the component part, and currently not supported. Also, I note your model specifies the same probability of zero for each condition, and from your description I wonder if that is a good idea. It's pretty easy to get wonderful-looking residuals when a model really fits badly -- that's an irony of residual diagnostics.

Comment: Thank you for responding to my question. Regarding the zero-inflation probability, I tried fitting zero-inflation as a function of type, but that gave exactly the same result. I also tried some other factors (some continuous, others categorical), same result. I tried modelling dispersion using "type" (as it might be logical to think that variance changes with factor levels), models looked either really bad or gave the same result. Regarding emmeans, contrasts are still significant for a factor level whose mean is close to 0, but not 100% 0s, but full 0 one is not...rather odd